# How do I remove a bunch of dynamically created things from the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am trying to delete a bunch of different things from the stage all at once.
I have 3 dynamically created text fields and 2 dynamically created movie clips.
I added them to the stage through my document class buy creating them, editing their properties and then...

```
addChild(myText1);
addChild(myText2);
addChild(myText3);
addChild(myMovieClip1);
addChild(myMovieClip2);
```

I want to delete them all and I have tried...

```
removeChild(myText1);
```

ETC

But this doesn't work.
can anyone help me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove everything from the current object, you can do :

```
while (numChildren > 0) removeChildAt(0);
```

If your DisplayObjects are on the stage, you can do :

```
stage.removeChild(myText1);
```

Comment: It isn't in an object though, it is just on the stage. There are other things on the stage as well so I don't want everything removed, just the 3 text fields and the 2 movieclips.

Comment: Edited my answer. If that still doesn't work, please explain : Do you have a exception ? It just does nothing ?

Comment: I think what my issue is, is that I can't delete the children because they are in a separate function and not a global variable, therefor I can't access them from my separate method because I can't refference them. But there has to be a way to access them if they are on the stage, so I guess I am trying to find out how to remove them from the stage. I just tried stage.removeChild(myText1); But I still get Access of undefined property myText1.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to be able to delete those specific objects, then you'll need to store references to them somewhere.

An alternative solution would be to populate the .name property of each object when you create it, and then use that name at a future time to grab a reference to the object:

```
var __dynamicMovieClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
__dynamicMovieClip.name = "foo";

addChild(__dynamicMovieClip);
```

And then at some later time:

```
removeChild(getChildByName("foo"));
```

getChildByName carries quite a bit of overhead though, so it's really not a good idea to call it repeatedly, or in a situation where the current display list is complex/deep

Comment: Thank you heaps, I think I might just have to store them in a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have member variables for each of the dynamically created objects so you can reference them outside of the function you used to create them. If you only need a reference to remove them from the stage, an array will work great.

```
private var objectsToDelete : Array = [];

private function someFunction ( ) : void
{
    objectsToDelete.push(myText1);
    objectsToDelete.push(myText2);
    objectsToDelete.push(myText3);
    objectsToDelete.push(myMovieClip1);
    objectsToDelete.push(myMovieClip2);
}

private function removeObjects () : void
{
    var i : int = 0;
    var max : int = objectsToDelete.length;
    for ( i; i < max; i++ )
    {
        removeChild( objectsToDelete[ i ] );
    }
}
```